# Does each member of an ensemble have to be composed of the same model type?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, ensemble-learning

I am interested in ensemble modeling and have researched a lot a about how people create their ensemble model.

But there are different ways that people create it and I am confused which one is correct.

I will list out the types and please tell me which one is the correct way to create an ensemble classification model.

**Type 1. Creates 10 models with the same algorithm but different parameters.**

For example, KNN(k=1),KNN(k=2),KNN(k=3),...KNN(k=10).

**Type 2. Creates 10 models with 10 different algorithms.**

For example, SVC,NuSVC,Naive Bayes,Bernoulli Naive Bayes, Gaussian Naive Bayes,...

**p.s. I have learned that SVC and NuSVC is SVM but is implemented differently. Should these two be treated as different algorithms because they do the same thing. Same about the different Naive Bayes algorithms**

Answer (score 2):

Actually both ways are valid & selection of the approach is based on performance on particular dataset.

For competitions on Kaggle, winners have used both of them together as well to get small jump the leaderboard.

Refer to below practical guide on model ensemble -
http://mlwave.com/kaggle-ensembling-guide/

The effectiveness of the method will vary from problem to problem but in most cases I have seen method2 being more effective than one.